# Can I input a PHP file to ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I want to use ffmpeg, but pass in a PHP file (which will perform some logic, and then output a video file).

I know you can do this on webservers, i.e. create "image.jpg" but have it contain PHP code, and when someone visits it, it will run as a PHP script.

If I run the PHP file, it outputs a video file, and if I pass a video file directly, the stream works so I know those parts are fine by themselves.

However, I believe the issue is that the PHP file will never be processed as a PHP file, whereas a webserver would know that? So do I need to somehow trick it or create an alias file or similar to process the PHP file and return the video output?

I thought maybe I could pass in a bash file, which runs the PHP script using the php command but that didn't work.

I'm not sure what else to try or where to look

Comment: You can't put PHP code in an image/video file. You can configure your webserver to execute files with `.jpg` extensions as PHP, and the PHP script would output image data.

Comment: @Barmar sorry yes, that's what I was trying to imply. Can I configure my server to process .mp4 files with PHP?

Comment: Sure. You can configure it to use a particular processor by extension and/or by folder. So you could say that everything in a particular directory should be processed by PHP, regardless of the extension.

Comment: You could also keep the `.php` extension, and use that as the URL for an `<img>` or `<video>` tag.

Comment: Simple answer is, no.  FFMpeg is a tool for processing video.  It does not allow for scripting with php.  There are however, ways of wrapping the many options for processing video files with ffmpeg.  For a social media company I built an asset storage and transpiling system which utilized ffmpeg as the primary video conversion tool.  At the time I started with an early version of this library: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg.  The most difficult part was getting a version of ffmpeg built that had all the features I needed.

Comment: I think one solution might be to run a webserver accessible locally only and serve videos that way? seems like unnecessary overhead but it should work

Comment: [What is the _actual_ problem that you're trying to solve?](https://xyproblem.info/)